# Detect a word and addClass to body

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery below detects the word `first` and `third` in any `<p>` text and adds a yellow or red background to it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p:contains(first)").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $("p:contains(third)").css("background-color", "red");
});

<p>I'm the first sentence.</p>
<p>I'm the second sentence.</p>
<p>I'm the third sentence.</p>
<p>I'm the fourth sentence.</p>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3p0nmw4f/1/

However, instead of highlighting the text, I want to `addClass` to the body of the html document like this :

```
<body class="first">
```

or

```
<body class="third">
```

I know we can achieve this using `$(document.body).addClass('first');` but I'm unable to put it together.

Please help.

Comment: What is the purpose of changing the colour or class. Is it for styling reasons?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fk05dabw/

Comment: _I'm unable to put it together._ do you mean you want multiple classes in body or just one from them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could search for the closest body HTML element.
You can do this by doing the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p:contains(first)").closest('body').addClass('first');
  $("p:contains(third)").closest('body').addClass('third');
});
```

---

Another possibility would be to simply search for the body element as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("p:contains(first)"))
    $("body").addClass("first")
  if ($("p:contains(third)"))
    $("body").addClass("third")
});
```

Source: https://jsfiddle.net/fk05dabw/

Comment: How many `<body>` elements are there going to be in the document?  (just kidding, works quite well if OP doesn't want to use `if ($("p:contains(first)").length)`)